# Material-ui v5 - where is DataGrid component? ( How to install DataGrid component in material-ui v5 In react?)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I upgraded material-ui/core to version `5.0.0-beta.1` and material-ui/lab to version `5.0.0-alpha.30` and I can not locate `DataGrid` component. It is not present in neither material-ui/core nor material-ui/lab. Furhermore, v5 docs for DataGrid is empty. Where is DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install it via following command:

```
npm i @material-ui/data-grid
```

See this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/data-grid

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @mui/x-data-grid`

`yarn add @mui/x-data-grid`

You can check this link out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-data-grid